# C++/OF iterating objects that change property each iteration?

Tags: c++

What I am trying to do: create a series of rectangles generated each frame next to each other. Each rectangle's height is based on the frequency of sound at that moment, then the iterator moves on to the next rectangle, leaving the last at the proper height.

What is happening: The screen just becomes a big singular block, with all spaces constantly moving up and down with the frequency... I can't seem to get it to iterate one at a time, not changing them all constantly.

What I think my issue is: I have no idea how to get each iteration to store and save its own values, even though the values are part of the object...

The Code in question:

```
float bldgHeighTemp;        

for (int i = 0; i <  1000 ; i+=30){   
    for (int f = 0; f < (int)(BUFFER_SIZE/2); f++){   
        bldg temp;   
        bldgs.push_back(temp);   
        bldgs[i].bldgPosX = i;   
        bldgs[i].bldgPosY = ofGetHeight()/2;   
        bldgs[i].bldgWidth = 30;   
        bldgs[i].bldgHeight = bldgHeighTemp;   
        bldgs[i].draw();   
        bldgHeighTemp = freq[f]*-6;    
    }
}
```

How do I implement this properly?

Answer (score 0):

You set `bldgs[i].bldgHeight = bldgHeighTemp;` and then set `bldgHeighTemp = freq[f]*-6;` second. In other words, `bldgHeighTemp` is used before it's set.

Your inner loop adds a new item to `bldgs` each iteration, but you use the same one `bldgs[i]` even after pushing a new one. I'm not quite sure I can figure out what you're actually trying to do though.

Comment: Ok the first part makes sense...

The second part, I have an object bldg.h,bldg.cpp and call it in a vector  vector <bldg> bldgs;

Does that make sense?

Comment: I want to add a new rectangle each frame. Am I doing that incorrectly?

Comment: Am I pushing it back in the wrong place? I feel like I'm missing something here...

Comment: you're pushing back while filling then of the the old rectangles. What makes you think that `blgds[i]` is the last element?

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite it this way:

```
float bldgHeighTemp;        

for (int i = 0; i <  1000 ; i+=30){   
    for (int f = 0; f < (int)(BUFFER_SIZE/2); f++){   
        bldg temp;
        temp.bldgPosX = i;   
        temp.bldgPosY = ofGetHeight()/2;   
        temp.bldgWidth = 30;   
        temp.bldgHeight = freq[f]*-6;   
        temp.draw();   

        bldgs.push_back(temp);   
    }
}
```

The problem with your code is that it adds more elements than it assigns properties to, make sure you understand it.

Say `BUFFER_SIZE == 10`, then the internal loop ( `for( int f =...`) would run for 5 times, so `blgds.push_back()` would be called 1000 * 5 = 5000 times! But you only assign to `blds[i]`, where `i < 1000` (this is guaranteed by the loop title). So, `blgs[i]` where `i >= 1000`, so atually, the majority of your objects, are left uninitialized.

Comment: That makes sense, what I want to do is push back after all the other declarations?

Comment: Also, any idea how I get each bldg[i] to have its own frequency? I tried making a vector of frequencies, but then the rectangle disappeared altogether. 

Thanks!

Comment: @user, what do you mean by frequency here?

Comment: Thanks for responding :)   I want to use audio input to control the height of the buildings, basically like a sound visualizer, but instead of them changing constantly, I will be having new ones drawn to the right every frame or so, and then translate everything to the left. Thinking is making a long city scape based on noise. 

So, when I talk of frequency, I mean the measured frequency at each second or frame (haven't decided that part yet)

Comment: @user, you should probably create a separate question for this. I would consider adding a member to your `bldg` structure for the frequency. Buildings don't disappear because you try some approach (creating a vector of frequencies), they disappear because of a programming error while implementing, so I cannot tell much without the code.

Comment: @user, this is Q&A site, so long discussions are uncommon here

Comment: Ok, Ill try asking in a different way. It's hard when you only half know how to ask what you need to ask.